# IntelliJ IDEA cannot import dependency

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I'm having a problem with maven dependencies in IntelliJ IDEA.
What does curly red lines mean under dependencies ?
Is there a conflict between dependencies or IDEA could not find dependency?
How can I solve this problem?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Did you check the `<repository>` is configured in your root pom?

Comment: I do not have <repository> tag in my root pom.xml.

Comment: Well there you go, that is probably why it can't find it. Which repository can you find it in, if you use a web browser? Then try adding that to your pom, hit reload maven projects and see if it can be found.

Comment: I found that there are some repositories while searching maven settings of IntelliJ and one of the repos includes sqoop. By the way when I try another release of Sqoop(e.g 1.4.0-incubating) red curly line disappears. I guess something another causes this problem.

Comment: Well I could see sqoop-1.4.0.incubating in some of the main apache repos, so that would be because maven could find it. If you need 1.5.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT for some reason, copy it to your local nexus server or failing that your local repo.

Answer (score 0):

If your project build perfectly, you have to set your local repository in IDEA setting. Then re-import maven dependencies. This should resolve all dependencies. But make sure you build your project first without errors.

Comment: It does not build perfectly. When I try another release of sqoop (e.g  1.4.0-incubating), it builds. However I need a newer verison of sqoop.